# How to aggregate sum all the columns in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

For the following `datatable`, is there a way to get the expected result without having to specify all the columns one by one? the problem here is that my real table has 20+ columns. I am looking for a cleaner solution.

### Expected Result

```
Col1Sum | Col2Sum | Col3Sum | Col4Sum
--------------------------------------
3       | 3       | 3       | 3
```

### Table + Query

```
datatable(Col1: int, Col2: int, Col3: int, Col4: int)
[
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
]
| summarize
  Col1Sum = sum(Col1),
  Col2Sum = sum(Col2),
  Col3Sum = sum(Col3),
  Col4Sum = sum(Col4);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the query using a Kusto query:

```
datatable(Col1: int, Col2: int, Col3: int, Col4: int)
[
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1,
]
| getschema 
| extend SumColumn = strcat(ColumnName,  "Sum = sum(", ColumnName, ") ")
| summarize replace('"|\\[|]', "", tostring(make_list(SumColumn)))
| project Query = strcat("summarize ", Column1)
```

[image]